# replace div when screenwidth is bigger than 768px

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

the website:
http://wouterschaeffer.nl/bt/

When the screen width gets bigger than 768px, the div containing the blocks has to move up so it's just beneath the carousel.

I think it can be solved with jQuery but I don't know how

Comment: google for *CSS media queries*. Perhaps this will help you

Comment: Please provide a code example. Your link will be useless once you'll change your site.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it with jquery try this

```
function resize(){
 if($(window).width >768){

 //do somthing here with css 

}


} 
resize();
$(window).resize(function(){

resize();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know how to do it in regular Javascript, and it is fairly simple.

`var x = document.body(); 
if(screen.width >= 768){
    //code goes here
}`

That's all I did, but if you wanted to get the size of the window, you would replace screen.width, with window.innerHeight/window.innerWidth to get the size of the browser window